# python 3 and pyserial 2.7

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm trying to communicate with a serial device in Python, the device needs a sync byte which in this case is 255 then varying other bytes which as said "vary"
my code has this and works well

```
serial.write(b '255')
serial.write(b '55')
serial.write(b '69')
```

This works great but I cannot seem to substitute the last two numbers for variables as in

```
serial.write(b '255')
serial.write(b varA)
serial.write(b varB)
```

It seems as though this option is not available.

Please please Help me out

Answer (score 1):

`b'255'` is actually a binary representation of ascii string "255". If you want to pass exactly byte 255 you can simply write `serial.write(255)`. And in this case variables must be assigned with byte (just int in range from 0 to 255).

```
serial.write(255)
serial.write(55)
serial.write(69)

varA = 55
varB = 69
serial.write(255)
serial.write(varA)
serial.write(varB)
```

---

If its actually need a binary representation of ascii string (why?) and varA\varB is a string, you can convert it to a byte array. `varA = '255'; varA.encode('ascii')` the same as `b'255'`.